# Unresolved error with browsing a website : Error 404

Tags: server, firefox, proxy, firewall

I am running on Ubuntu 13.04 64amd.

I cannot access the website which I built online through all my browsers. It redirect to the server and it says the Error 404.

I asked from the server (Through email). They confirmed It is running well and asked me to check with proxy servers. I gone through a proxy server and could see the website running. I asked from a friend to check with his machine (Who is in my country) he confirmed the site is visible.

So in order to access it normally I cleaned all the browser history and cookies. But it wasn't resolved.

Then I cleaned all the browser files with the application Sweeper. Still problem exists.

I deleted the Firefox and Chromium cache files. Still problem exists.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running this simple commands, the problem resolved.

```
firefox [URL]

chromium-browser [URL]
```